# Add EC2 instance public IP to local Ansible hosts file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, terraform

I am creating an AWS EC2 instance, using terraform, and I want to put the newly created machine's public IP to my local /etc/ansible/hosts file. Tried to do it with local_file terraform module, but without success. Do you have any idea how can I pull this information with terraform ?
It should be something in this format for the hosts file :

A.B.C.D ansible_ssh_user=user ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/private/key

A.B.C.D will be the newly created instance's IP address.

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64075693/ansible-hosts-file-skipping-lines-when-hosts-key-checking-true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an `output` for the IP address you want to expose in an `output.tf` file in Terraform.  Something similar to:

```
output "private_ips" {
    value = "${aws_instance.<name>.private_ip}"
}
```

You can then call it from the command line using `terraform output private_ips`

One quick and dirty way to append it to your `/etc/ansible/hosts` file would be:

```
ip=`terraform output private_ips` ; echo "$ip ansible_ssh_user=user \
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/private/key" >> /etc/ansible/hosts
```

**References**

https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/outputs.html

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html